# Scope of questions?

Tags: discussion

Just saw this question: [User accessibility for mobile applications](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/268/user-accessibility-for-mobile-applications/270)

Totally legit question, but VERY broad in scope (and totally impossible to find a single correct answer for). Should there be a theoretical "maximum" scope of questions? Broad questions should be OK ("What should I think about while designing for Estonian users?") but there should be some sort of limit at which the question becomes too huge to effectively answer ("What should I think about when designing for international users?")

Comment: I agree. The linked question is too broad.

Answer (score 3):

I think several of the questions so far have been too broad. I can't say it better than the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

> **Ask real, expert questions.**
>   We want
>   you to capture the moment that
>   plumbers feel when they look at
>   PlumberOverflow and say, "Whoa! That's
>   my kinda site!" On a site about
>   plumbing, there are 200 easy plumbing
>   questions, and they've all been asked
>   100 times on other sites. Don't
>   suggest questions like "How do I
>   unclog a drain." Instead ask, "If you
>   run 2.5 GPM through 50 feet of 1/2"
>   galv pipe, how many psi will be lost
>   to friction loss?" Remember, the pro
>   sites WILL attract the enthusiasts,
>   but not the other way around!

In these first few days and weeks, I think we need to be especially careful to ask and encourage questions that are limited in scope.

Answer (score 1):

The questions should have a single, correct answer, especially right now. Over time I'm sure some of the broader "easy questions" will work their way in but for now we should be very critical of the types of questions we're asking.

I think the question is both too broad and shows little effort. On SO it's looked down upon when the OP is just looking for some free slave labor, but is rewarded when they've narrowed their question down to a single problem, worked with it, stated exactly what they just can't seem to figure out.

UI is different from programming but I think the same concept fits here -- if this question showed some effort then (I think) much of the broad unanswerable nature could be avoided, and it could be nailed down to a few specific things that the OP finds hard about mobile vs. desktop UI.