# I've got several good answers, must I pick one?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So I asked about what are the idioms for drop:

[What are the common idioms for the drop portion of a drag and drop operation?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/281/what-are-the-common-idioms-for-the-drop-portion-of-a-drag-and-drop-operation)

There are several good answers, and what I like is that each one addresses a separate idiom.  I want to "accept"  the best answer for each idiom, but I can accept only one.  Do I have to pick my favorite child or beg for someone to write a rollup answer?  Can multiple accepted answers be codede into stack exchange?

Answer (score 6):

There can only be one accepted answer.

You could do one of the following:

a) Accept none of the answers, but up-vote all the ones that helped. Add a comment to these answers and hope that it encourages others to up-vote these answers too.

b) Up-vote all of the ones that helped and accept one.

c) Up-vote answers, accept one and the start a bounty to award to one of the other answers that helped. This will cost you a minimum of 50 rep, so I'd do it with great caution. You can repeat this to reward other answers.

d) Create your own answer that sums up all the useful points and then accept that.

There are probably other options I haven't thought of.

Comment: I think option d) is the best here, just make sure to provide reference with permalink to all the answers you liked, to encourage others to upvote them.

Answer (score 2):

That's part of why I advocate [asking questions that are as narrowly focused as possible](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27/scope-of-questions/28#28).

Compare the linked question to a related one, [How to visualize the possibility of dragndrop](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/216/how-to-visualize-the-possibility-of-dragndrop). That question is slightly more constrained; it mentions a *web application* and *sorting*. I think it's a little easier to compare the answers against one another because you can imagine how each solution would work in a specific context.

That question could have been even better if a screenshot, link, and/or more details about the specific things being sorted were provided.

***However,*** I think choosing an accepted answer on this site is going to much more difficult than it is on Stack Overflow. Even there, I consider an 80% accept rate a reasonable goal.

Comment: **Full disclosure:** I wrote the most popular answer to the linked question. It also happens to be my most successful answer to date.

Comment: Coincidence??  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or, we could gather up a ton of questions that don't have one clear answer in a meta question and then present that to the SE dev team as proof that UI is an example of an SE site where the "one answer to rule them all" design doesn't work as well.

We'd have to wait a bit for that to happen but it might be worth doing.

Comment: This is very interesting, as we're struggling with the same issue on the Area51 proposal for an Information Retrieval and Search Engines Stack Exchange site. See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39142/information-retrieval-and-search-engines . I hope that with enough examples of recall-oriented answers, we can convince the Stack Exchange folks that some disciplines can benefit from multiple answers.